# How To Set Product URL Key OR Redirect URL in PHP

Tags: product, url, create

So I am creating a Magento product when I call this if statement and it returns false, that all works...

**I just want to create the URL or create a URL redirect for the product in the same statement**

It needs to be within the same if statement as I want it to be created at the same time of the product creation

Here is my code:

```
if (!Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku))  {

  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $product->setName($name);
  $product->setSku($sku);
  $product->setDescription($desc);
  $product->setShortDescription($short);

  $stock_data=array(
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
    'qty' => 0,
    'min_qty' => 0,
    'use_config_min_qty'=>0,
    'min_sale_qty' => 1,
    'use_config_min_sale_qty'=>1,
    'max_sale_qty' => 9999,
    'use_config_max_sale_qty'=>1,
    'is_qty_decimal' => 0,
    'backorders' => 0,
    'notify_stock_qty' => 0,
    'is_in_stock' => 0
  );

  $product->setData('stock_data',$stock_data);
  $product->setTaxClassId(2);     // default tax class
  $product->setAttributeSetId(4); //9 is for default

  $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
  $product->setCategoryIds(array(9));
  $product->setStatus(1);//1=Enabled; 2=Disabled;
  $product->setVisibility(4);//4 = catalog &amp; search.

  try
  {
    $product->save();
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try using `setUrlKey()` like this:

```
$url = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', $name);
$url = strtolower($url);
$product->setUrlKey($url);
```

Otherwise I think you may need to rewrite the product url.

Take a look at:

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php`, `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url` and `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite`

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `$product->setUrlKey(..);` which sets the url key you want. Probably you need to rebuild the catalog_url index after saving.

Comment: This doesn't work. I should have stated this in my original question. I always end up getting the name converted into a url-encoded string automatically set as the URL. $product->setUrlKey($sku); does not have any effect.

Comment: Did you flush the cache and reindex the catalog_url? This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yes of course, the URL key is always automatically set to a string version of the name of the product.

Comment: To clarify, if i do not set a name fort the product then no URL is generated, even if I try to set $product -> setUrlKey($url);

Comment: Maybe for some reason your url key is a store view/website specific setting?

Comment: Can you help me find out whether or not this is true? What would I do if this is the case? Could it be that I am not setting the urlkey in the right place?

Comment: I guess you check the url-key settings in the backend, right? If it's correct for the standard settings you'll have to check the settings for the sore views and set them explicitly in you import script.

Comment: If you are talking about the settings Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations I have already tested to see if any of the URL settings do anything but none seem to change the fact that a URL is generated from the Name of the Product.

Comment: How about a separate solution, where I set the Name as what I desire to be set as the URL and then in the same function, set the name back to what I want the name to actually be, after the URL is generated. Does this seem like the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using preg_replace

it's better to use in formatUrlKey() of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product

you can send it any string yow want

(recommended to add the sku to the product name)